# How do I release an updated Core Data schema without affecting existing users' data?

Tags: iphone, core-data

I am about to be releasing an app that is heavily dependant on its use of core data. Am I right in thinking that any changes made to the core data structure will cause users to lose all of their saved data (when updating the app)?

What is a good method to ensure this doesn't happen? Is it suitable to create extra fields in my data - just extra NSStrings - so that they are there for use, should I require an extra field in the future?

All thoughts and opinions greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Data includes the concept of model versions and migration between them.  In some cases it can be done without too much effort and in more complex cases may required work by the programmer.  There's a reference for it online: [Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html)